# change timeout of rostest

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test a lot of topics with hztest ros.org/wiki/rostest/Nodes (no Karma no Link)
Since all tests are launched in their own environment, it takes more than one hour to complete the testing, and nobody can use the robot.
Because of that, I created a modified hztests to check all given topics in one bringup.
But when I check more than about 6 topics the time limit is hit and the test fails:

File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/launch.py", line 669, in run_test
raise RLTestTimeoutException("test max time allotted")

I successfully changed line 664:
timeout_t= time.time()+test.time_limit to timeout_t= time.time()+1000.0

But is there a  way to change the time_limit without manipluating ros_comm?

I tried 'rostest mypckg mytest --bare-limit=1000' and also setting a parameter time_limit on the parameter server, but both without success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50865/change-timeout-of-rostest/) by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameter is time-limit not time_limit. So it's

---

Originally posted by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) with karma: 181 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6